# The triangle does not show on page, code worked for all the other shapes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the shapes to appear in a random order, all seems to work apart from triangle.  If i take the style.display: none out it shows the triangle but in the if statement i set it to "block to make it come back.  circle and square both work but I don't understand why triangle  does not come back`enter code here.

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Test Your Reactions</title>
    
    
     <style type="text/css">
                
    
                 #circle {
                    
                    width:130px;
                    height:130px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    float:left;
                    margin-right:50px;
                    background-color: red;
                    
                }
               
    
               
      
      
    
     #square{
    
      background-color: blue;
     
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 40px;
      float: left;
     }
    
     #triangle {
        width         : 0;
        height        : 0;
        border-left   : 100px solid transparent;
        border-right  : 100px solid transparent;  
        border-bottom : 100px solid #aaa;
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body>
    
    <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
    
    <h4>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</h4>
    
    <p>Your time: </p>
    
    <div id="circle"style="display: none;"></div>
    
    <div id="square" style = "display: none;"></div>
    
    <div id="triangle" style ="display: none;"></div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var shapes = new Array();
    
    shapes [0] = "triangle";
    shapes [1] = "square";
    shapes [2] = "circle";
    
    
    var randomAnswer = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapes.length)];
    
    
    
    
    if (randomAnswer == "triangle"){
     
     document.getElementById("triangle").style.dispaly ="block";
    }
    if (randomAnswer == "square"){
    
     document.getElementById("square").style.display = "block";
    }
    if (randomAnswer == "circle"){
    
     
     document.getElementById("circle").style.display = "block";
    
    
     //document.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = function() {
                                  
        //document.getElementById("red-circle").style.display = "none";
    
       // alert("circle clicked");
    }
    
    </script> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It’s a typo: `dispaly`

Comment: no way sorry been looking at that for ages

Comment: can any one explain why this question has received so many negative votes, messing up mu account.  i am learning web design from scratch by my self and need places like this to help my learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

document.getElementById("triangle").style.**dispaly** ="block";

If you correct that, it should work

Comment: no need to answer when it's a typo, flag the question instead

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't know that! but i don't have the option to flag anything yet... level 1 account ... so I can't do it... but you voted me negative without looking the level ... BRAVO

Comment: i have been banned from asking any more questions an i think its because of this question not sure why????

Comment: I guess because they vote you negative... I don't know mate. I am new in this community as well... maybe someone with more experience can tell you something